# Plotting 5 horizontal bar plot in the same row

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

[Horizontal bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPxvk.png)

So I would like to plot that bar for the five different boroughs in New York using
fig, ax = plt.subplots() in the same row with five different horizontal bar plot but I don't know how to do it.

Can someone help?

Thank you really much!!!

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal example?

Comment: Do you have an example of the plot you want? What do you mean by all in the same row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5) = plt.subplots(1, 5)
```

Now, you can use each axis object to plot 1 bar plot like:

```
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2.plot(x, y**2, 'tab:orange')
ax3.plot(x, -y, 'tab:green')
ax4.plot(x, -y**2, 'tab:red')
ax5.plot(x, -y**3, 'tab:blue')
```